# What is returned?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm reading JavaScript written with React,Redux,and Thunk in an example below:

In actions.js to create action:

```
function fetchPosts(subreddit){
    return dispatch => {
            dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))
            return fetch(`...URL...`)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(subreddit, json)))
    }
}

export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(subreddit) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
      return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
    }
  }
```

**What does "fetchPosts(subreddit)" return?**  .

**I can't understand what "return dispatch =>" is**.

This function is imported and used in a container to dispatch action,so I 
think "dispatch" is a function imported from 'react-redux'in the container as below:

```
import {fetchPostsIfNeeded} from "../actions"
import {connect} from "react-redux"
...
componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }
...
```

Does "dispatch" before arrow mean a function, "dispatch(requestPosts(subreddit))"?

Is dispatch a argument as which "(dispatch)" is abbreviated with ES2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions :

```
// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter:
(singleParam) => { statements }
singleParam => { statements }
```

So, `dispatch => {...}`, is making an arrow function with one parameter, `dispatch`.  `fetchPosts(subreddit)` returns a single arrow function.

The nonsense about `{ disppatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props` is something called Destructuring Assignment.  The manual: [MDN Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

The essence of it is:

```
var o = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p, q} = o;
console.log(p); // 42
console.log(q); // true
```

So yes, `dispatch` is being pulled from `this.props`, which is appearantly a reactjs component thing! [ReactJS Components and Props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: Thank you! I understood this "dispatch" is a function, and returns a arrow function.
when all "dispatch" in this function are changed into other name, this function still worked as you said.
Thank you very much!